# How to fix Unpickling Error when sending video data via sockets in Python?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, opencv, pickle

I have the following two files:

SERVER.PY

> ```
> import socket
> import cv2
> import pickle
> import struct
>
> HOST = '192.168.0.17'
> PORT = 8083
>
> s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> print('Socket created')
>
> s.bind((HOST, PORT))
> print('Socket bind complete')
> s.listen(10)
> print('Socket now listening')
>
> conn, addr = s.accept()
>
> data = b''
> payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")
>
> while True:
>     while len(data) < payload_size:
>         data += conn.recv(4096)
>     packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
>
>     data = data[payload_size:]
>     msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]
>
>     while len(data) < msg_size:
>         data += conn.recv(4096)
>     frame_data = data[:msg_size]
>     data = data[msg_size:]
>
>     frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
>     print(frame.size)
>     cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
>     cv2.waitKey(10)
> ```

CLIENT.PY

> ```
> import cv2
> import socket
> import pickle
> import struct
>
> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
> clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
> clientsocket.connect(('192.168.0.17', 8083))
>
> while True:
>     ret,frame = cap.read()
>     data = pickle.dumps(frame)
>     clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data)) + data)
> ```

When I run this on the same computer on localhost, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run the server on one computer and the client on another one (same local network), I get the following error:

> File "C:/Users//Desktop/server.py", line 35, in 
> frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
> _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.

Maybe I should mention that I am running the server.py file on a Windows machine and the client.py on a Linux machine. The connection works but as soon as I connect, I get the error message above. Any ideas?